# Display "uncaught exception" page as content-type text/html

Tags: 8

When there is an uncaught exception, Drupal 8 displays a simple dump of the exception.

I find that the page is served as 'Content-Type' = 'text/plain', yet it contains HTML:
[image: Error as plain text]

It looks better to me when I change the code to serve as 'text/html':
[image: Error as HTML]

I already found the code to change - it's in FinalExceptionSubscriber.php, which outputs

- `</br></br>`
- [SafeMarkup::format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21SafeMarkup.php/function/SafeMarkup%3A%3Aformat/8.4.x)(...) which is documented as

> Formats a string for HTML display by replacing variable placeholders.

My question is:

1. Does anyone know a reason why the error page is text/plain given that it contains HTML.
2. Shall I raise an issue and patch?

Comment: Because this is the most generic exception subscriber for exceptions not handled by any format specific exception subscriber (like html or json).

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for explaining.  However it seems that the exceptions do contain HTML.  The <br><br> is always there and SafeMarkup::format description is "Formats a string for HTML display by replacing variable placeholders"

Comment: (Question edited to clarify that the output does contain HTML)

Comment: Yes, that's a bit inconsistent. But you would never show this message in production. If you want to react to a custom exception you would do this in your own exception subscriber.

Comment: @4k4 I agree this will not occur in production.  My scenario is _not_ to react to a custom exception.  My scenario is that when I'm debugging it's tedious to try to read text that contains HTML tags.  Sorry if I'm being slow, but I still don't understand any reason not to change it to text/html.

Comment: This would revert this issue [Standardize fatal error/exception handling: backtrace for all formats, not just HTML](https://www.drupal.org/node/2853300). Better follow up on this issue and improve the text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @4k4, so it seems that this is a minor bug, but the obvious fix would revert the "Standardize handling" issue.

I have raised [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2924860) and linked it to the other issue.  I don't really understand the code here and would welcome any help to improve the issue text.